# Can Mail manage contacts?

Tags: pantheon-mail

Can I manage my mail contacts in the Mail app that is shipped by default in Juno ? (pantehon-mail I guess, but since the application has no "About" menu entry I can't really tell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. It can auto complete when filling in known addresses though. I can't, however tell you exactly how that works, though I believe it uses the evolution backend.